# Sharepoint Group Group ID

Tags: groups, power-automate

Does anyone know if the flow action "list group members" supports getting group membership for SharePoint Group?

If so, how can I figure out what the group ID is?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "List group members" action can only get Office 365 groups. It does not allow us to get membership of SharePoint Groups.

To get sharepoint groups, you can use the rest API call. Refer [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/SharePoint-Group-Operations-in-Microsoft-Flow/ba-p/394446).

Comment: thank you very much